# How to find the intersection of two power sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given $R$ and $T$ be sets defined as follows.

$R = \{2,4,6,7,8\}$

$T = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}:x \leq 4 \,\text{or}\, x \geq 8\}$

Question: Find the following

$\mathcal{P}(R)\cap \mathcal{P}(T)$

What is the solution to this? I'm confused about how to find the power set of $T$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{Hi Ben, hope this answer isn't overlong.}$

You have two sets, $R$, and $T$.

$R$ contains numbers $2,4,6,7,8$.

$T$ contains all integers less than or equal to $4$ and all integers greater than or equal to $8$. I.e., contains all integers, **except** $5, 6, 7$.

The expression $\mathcal P(R)\cap \mathcal P(T)$ represents the intersection of the power sets of $R$ and $T$. The power set of a set is the set of all of the set's subsets. That means it includes only values found in the original set. The intersection of two power sets therefore excludes all subsets in which values not common to the two original sets are found. So:

$\mathcal P(R)\cap \mathcal P(T) = \mathcal P(R\cap T)$

To compute $R\cap T$:

Notice that $R$ contains integers between $4$ and $8$--namely, $6,7$. But $T$ does not. Removing these, the intersection $R\cap T$ = $\{2,4,8\}$.

The answer is the power set of this intersection:

$\mathcal P(R)\cap \mathcal P(T)$

$ = \mathcal P(R\cap T)$

$ = \mathcal P(\{2,4,8\}) $

$=  \boxed{\{\emptyset, \{2\}, \{4\}, \{8\}, \{2,4\}, \{4,8\}, \{2,8\}, \{2,4,8\}\}}$

Please reach out in the comments below if you are still uncertain as to how to solve this type of problem or if you are having additional questions or concerns.